# How do you extract the initial weights used in the model?

Tags: returnn

FRom the documentation I found that after contruction of a model, the weights are initialized by calling `TFNetwork.initialize_params`. I am wondering if there is an API to extract these weights?

Answer (score 0):

There is `TFNetwork.save_params_to_file`. Is that what you want?

Otherwise, you can simply access all the params individually. E.g. via `TFNetwork.get_trainable_params`, or `TFNetwork.get_param_values_dict`, or `TFNetwork.get_layer(layer_name).params`, etc.